# Appending data to file with a single open/close from a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I need to adjust my shell script and write to `$log` multiple times. Opening and closing the file repeatedly will cause an increase in runtime.

How can I write everything at once to the file, including all `echo` statements defined in my script?

```
#!/bin/sh
log="loadlog.log"

for i in {1..10}
do
   n=$((100*$i))
   echo "## Users=$i  requests=$n ##" >> $log     
   ab -n $n -c $i  http://mainserver.com/index.html  >>  $log
   ssh root@mainserver cat /proc/loadavg >> $log
   echo "======" >> $log
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not sure, but I guess you want to open the log file for writing just once, do you?

If so, you need to use a sub-shell, output to the STDOUT and, outside, send it to the log file.

```
#! /bin/bash
log="loadlog.log"

(
for i in {1..10}; do
    n=$((100*$i))

    echo "## Users=$i  requests=$n ##"

    ab -n $n -c $i  http://mainserver.com/index.html

    ssh root@mainserver cat /proc/loadavg

    echo "======"
done
) >> $log
```

As well, I recommend you to do something with your code-style—it’s unreadable. And, you need to use `#!/bin/bash` because you use bash-specific constructs in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `exec` command with a redirection applies that redirection to the whole script. So, you could redirect all stdout to append to the log file:

```
#!/bin/sh
log="loadlog.log"

exec 1>>$log

for i in {1..10}
do
   n=$((100*$i))
   echo "## Users=$i  requests=$n ##"
   ab -n $n -c $i  http://mainserver.com/index.html
   ssh root@mainserver cat /proc/loadavg
   echo "======"
done
```

If you still want to emit stuff to the user, you can make a copy of stdout first:

```
#!/bin/sh
log="loadlog.log"

exec 3>&1     # file descriptor 3 is now stdout
exec 1>>$log

for i in {1..10}
do
    # ...
   echo "======"                  # this line will be appended to the log file
   echo "completed loop $i" >&3   # this line will be displayed to user
done

exec 1>&3     # fd 1 restored to stdout
exec 3>&-     # fd 3 is closed

echo "stdout now restored"
```